# как сделать так, чтобы aiogram бот не прятал клавиатуру?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot

в telegram боте на aiogram есть клавиатура, которая появляется на старте, а есть, которая появляется по команде /admin. К той, которая при старте появляется, вопросов нет. Когда ввожу команду /admin, клавиатура появляется, но почему-то сворачивается. в чем может быть проблема?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['admin'])
async def admin_call(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id in admins:
        #клавиатура
        keyboard_admin = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button_admin_main_menu = types.KeyboardButton('Выйти')
        button_admin_stat = types.KeyboardButton('Статистика')
        button_admin_ban = types.KeyboardButton('❌Черный список')
        keyboard_admin.add(button_admin_main_menu, button_admin_stat, button_admin_ban)
        await message.answer('Меню администратора', reply_markup=keyboard_admin)
```

Comment: я проверил ваш код и у меня появляется клавиатура и никуда не девается, в чём проблема? возможно я не так понял

Answer (score 2):

За скрытие клавиатуры отвечает параметр **one_time_keyboard**, где **True** скрывает клавиатуру после клика.
Попробуйте дополнить:

```
keyboard_admin = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=False)
```

Comment: не помогло. я так понимаю, что это все из-за того, что мы вводим вручную в чате команду /admin. если сделать вход в админ-панель с клавиатуры, то такого не будет. не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы именно клавиатура кнопочная была приоритетом после текстового ввода команды /admin